# Is there any way to write a file with QtScript?

Tags: qt, qfile, qtscript, qt-installer

I want to make an installer with Qt. The configuration of the installer is written in a file named installscript.qs which is qtscript based
I tried to create a QFile inside but it didn't recognize it!
Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

To create a file in your installer script you can use below function

> installer.execute()

For example, to create an empty file (Linux platform), call this function as below

> installer.execute("touch", "file-path");

Or to append some text message to file , call this function as below

> installer.execute('/bin/sh', new Array('-c', 'echo some-sample-data >> file-path'));